# How to identify a folder and then decide whether to move it or not in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a linux issue that I would like some help with...

I have an application that creates directories for me. I'd like to write a script that looks at these directories, checks to see whether the directory starts with a certain string of characters, if it does, leave it alone, if it doesn't then move it...

So, from a logical stance:

If directoryname begins with "ABC" then do nothing
else
move folder to sharedrive
This script will go in the cron.hourly folder so it runs automatically for me.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name 'ABC*' -exec mv -i {} ./dest \;
```

If you can identify a simple pattern for the directories you don't want to move, you might even be able to use bash's extglob setting:

```
shopt -s extglob
mv !(ABC)*/ ./dest/
```

Comment: +1 for extglob. `find .` would issue an error since it also matches `.`

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple pattern, just use `find`,

```
find * -type d ! -name "ABC*" | while read f; do mv $f /tmp/test2; done
```

You could also use something like this, but it might have problems due to how find does the recursion.

```
find * -type d ! -name "ABC*" -exec mv {} /tmp/test2 \;
```

So you could instead just output the list of dirs to a file, and *then* move them.

Comment: I'd upvote this if the first `find` used -print0 and the read delimiter were `nul`. As is, the loop can break on odd filenames.